# Child element shifting parent div

Tags: css

I've searched quite a bit looking for an explanation as to why this behavior is occurring.

Essentially I've setup 2 columns, each with a nav bar and content area.

CSS

```
#mainContainer {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
#leftContainer, #rightContainer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
}
#leftBar, #rightBar {
    background-color: purple;
    height: 10%;
}
#leftMain, #rightMain {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 90%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="leftContainer">
        <div id="leftBar"></div>
        <div id="leftMain"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightContainer">
        <div id="rightBar"></div>
        <div id="rightMain"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I add an element to the nav bar in only one column it shifts the entire column down.
http://jsfiddle.net/qn6rs0q2/3/

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="leftContainer">
        <div id="leftBar">
            <button>Test</button>
        </div>
        <div id="leftMain"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightContainer">
        <div id="rightBar"></div>
        <div id="rightMain"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But if I add another element to the other column they line up again.
http://jsfiddle.net/qn6rs0q2/5/

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="leftContainer">
        <div id="leftBar">
            <button>Test</button>
        </div>
        <div id="leftMain"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightContainer">
        <div id="rightBar">
            <button>Test 2</button>
        </div>
        <div id="rightMain"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To clarify, I'm not looking for a solution to fix this behavior. Rather I'm hoping someone can explain the underlying reason behind why it's behaving as it is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many questions that has this issue but it's hard to search for them when the OP usually does not know what exactly to search for. As j08691 suggests, vertical aligning them to the top will solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the default vertical alignment of inline elements is the baseline. If you set the vertical alignment to top (or middle) for both sides, they line up as you want:

```
#leftContainer, #rightContainer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qn6rs0q2/6/)**